# Is it a good practice to bundle the npm dependencies code with our code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

Is it a good practice to bundle the npm dependencies' code with our code?

If Yes, then there will be no point in adding that module as npm dependency, as its code will be included in our bundle.
If No, how do I avoid bundling my dependencies with my module? (in webpack for example)

Comment: So you do not need to bundle it but you ask us if you should bundle it?

Comment: Can you please provide more context? For starters, is "our code" a library or a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your package will be consumed from CDN as a single JS file then it makes sense to bundle up your NPM dependencies

Else, we don't bundle the dependencies generally